# Hang on shut down

Tags: usb, kernel, shutdown, 20.04

I've just installed ubuntu 20.04 on a macbook pro 3,1. It has an SSD and BIOS boot partition rather than EFI (so I can load the NVIDIA drivers). I have no external USB devices attached.

On shutdown, I keep getting the error:

```
[12549.497192] hub 6-0:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -110)
[12550.557073] Kernal panic - not syncing: Timeout: Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler.
```

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people with lower versions of ubuntu, different hardware architectures and different specific error messages (although all to do with USB) have reported that switching off and removing the power solved the problem.

Somewhat unbelievingly I tried the trick and it has worked. In my case this meant disconnecting the power cable and pulling the battery out which on my mac is fortunately external.

I've been running for a couple of days now (touch wood) with clean shutdowns and clean boots.

No idea why...

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the similar issue on Macbook Late 2007 (white). Tried with Lubuntu, Fedora and Ubuntu 22.0.4. All these os has the similar issues of Hanging/Freezing during Shutdown. It's been frustrating to turn off by removing the battery every time. I am using this Laptop in an unattended mode (remote turn and turn off).   I suspect there are some services which are blocking the shutdown and the machines freezes with the spinning of the fan in full blast. Eventually it will end up draining the battery to 0.

I wrote a script which will help to do a clean shutdown.The trick is to reboot the system and inject a script to properly shutdown.

Steps :

1. Created a cronjob with the following

```
@reboot /home/nirmal/shut.sh
```

2. Used the following script to check for the flag

```
#!/bin/bash

 #Ignore this line as this is for turning on remotely via AC adapter  
 #sudo /usr/bin/setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0:1

 flagValue="`cat /home/nirmal/shutflag.txt`"

 if [ "$flagValue" -eq "1" ]; then

   echo 2 > /home/nirmal/shutflag.txt

 else

   echo 1 > /home/nirmal/shutflag.txt
   echo "Shutting down" 
   shutdown now 

 fi
```

3. Whenever I want to shutdown, i will issue a reboot command remotely via ssh.

This way problem solved of hanging issue during shutdown.